# Check if checkbox is checked

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have user titles, which are stored in database in this way. 1,2,6,10 and etc.
I want to check if the user already has this titles and if he does, to check the check box.

```
<?php
    $user_titles = explode(',', $user['titles']);
    //foreach($user_titles as $uTitles){
        //echo $uTitles;
    //}
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="1">Test1<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="2">Test2<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="3">Test3<br/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `checked` attribute to the checked ones.

`<input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="1" <?php if(in_array(1, $user_titles) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>>Test1<br/>`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the in_array.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you have the values stored as a string delimited by a comma.

Use an iteration method, for example:

```
<?php $checked = ''; ?>
<?php for($i = 1; $i <= count($possible_checkbox); $i++ ) { 
  if(in_array($i, $user_titles ) ) { $checked = 'checked'; } else {$checked = '' }
?>
  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" name="title[]" <?php echo $checked; ?> />  
<?php } ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move the titles to new array and iterate trough them. Inside the loop, check if the value is in the $user_titles array and add 'checked' to the input tag.

```
<?php
$titles = [
    1 => "Test1",
    2 => "Test2",
    3 => "Test3",
];

foreach ($titles as $value => $title) {
    $checked = in_array($value, $user_titles) ? 'checked' : '';
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="title[]" value="' . $value . '" ' . $checked . '>' . $title . '<br/>';
}
?>
```